# Mode Shape Bom Remote Client Examples

Tags: client, shapes, mode, byte-order-mark

I am trying to find some sample examples for modeshape-bom-remote-client. There are many projects available in GitHub with modeshape-bom-embedded, but I did not find any examples or sample code with modeshape-bom-remote-client. The only documentation that is available is how to add it as a pom entry.

Any links where I can find the same.

Answer (score 0):

On ModeShape Github, you can find some examples in Unit Tests for Rest :

```
ModeShapeRestClient client = new ModeShapeRestClient(
  "http://localhost:8090/modeshape/repo/default", "test", "password");

Repositories repositories = client.getRepositories();
```

https://github.com/ModeShape/modeshape/blob/master/modeshape-jdbc/src/test/java/org/modeshape/jdbc/rest/ModeShapeRestClientTest.java

and for JDBC Driver :
https://github.com/ModeShape/modeshape/blob/master/modeshape-jdbc/src/test/java/org/modeshape/jdbc/JcrHttpDriverIntegrationTest.java